# Why is interface variable instantiation possible?

Tags: c#, .net, variables, interface, instance

As far as I know, interfaces cannot be instantiated.

If this is true, why does the below code compile and execute? It allows you to create a variable interface. Why is this possible?

Interface:

```
public interface IDynamicCode<out TCodeOut>
{        
    object DynamicClassInstance { get; set; }
    TCodeOut Execute(string value = "");
}
```

InCode:

```
var x = new IDynamicCode<string>[10];
```

Result:

[image: Result]

**UPDATE:**

It only happens when array declared. Not a single instance.

Comment: You created an array.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're not instantiating an interface, but an array of that interface.

You can assign an instance of any class that implements `IDynamicCode<string>` to that array. Say you have `public class Foo : IDynamicCode<string> { }`, you can instantiate that and assign it to an element of that array:

```
var x = new IDynamicCode<string>[10];
x[5] = new Foo();
```

Instantiating the interface would not compile:

```
var bar = new IDynamicCode<string>();
```

Answer (score 13):

You're not creating an instance of the interface; you're creating an array which can hold a number of objects which conform to `IDynamicCode`. Initially, the entries have their default value, which is `null`.

Answer (score 6):

this is not creating an interface variable

this will create an array where each element implements the interface. if you write  `x[0] = new IDynamicCode<string>();` then you will get the error. all of the elements are `null`, so you need to assign each element an object which implements `IDynamicCode`

Answer (score 5):

Just an interesting side-note:

While not possible conceptually, syntactically **it is indeed possible to instantiate an interface** under specific circumstances.

.NET has something called a [CoClassAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.coclassattribute(v=vs.71).aspx) which tells the compiler to interpret marked interface as specified concrete type. Using this attribute would make the following code perfectly valid and not throw a compile time error (note that this is not an array as in the original post):

```
var x = new IDynamicCode<string>();
```

A typical declaration of such attribute would look like this:

```
[ComImport]
[Guid("68ADA920-3B74-4978-AD6D-29F12A74E3DB")]
[CoClass(typeof(ConcreteDynamicCode<>))]
public interface IDynamicCode<out TCodeOut>
{
    object DynamicClassInstance { get; set; }
    TCodeOut Execute(string value = "");
}
```

Should this attribute be ever used and if, then where? The answer is "mostly never"! However, there are a couple of scenarios specific to COM interop where this will provide to be a useful feature.

More can be read about the topic from the following links:

- [Who says you can’t instantiate an interface?](http://blog.marcgravell.com/2009/08/who-says-you-cant-instantiate-interface.html)
- [Is it ok to (ab)use CoClassAttribute to provide a default implementation for an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094441/is-it-ok-to-abuse-coclassattribute-to-provide-a-default-implementation-for-an)
- [How does the C# compiler detect COM types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093536/how-does-the-c-sharp-compiler-detect-com-types)

Comment: You're still not instanciating an interface. You're using an interface type in a *new-expression* but are instantiating a proxy object implementing that interface. It's worth noting that this is a case where a *new-expression* will not yield an object of the type specified in the expression.

Comment: That is completely true. Though the syntax of such expression is what can be considered "instantiating an interface" whereas in reality a concrete object is instantiated behind the scene through compiler knowledge of the CoClassAttribute.

Comment: You guys are both saying the same thing, but I prefer @Laurent LA RIZZA's way of stating it.  In this scenario you are making it _look_ like you are instantiating an interface, when in fact you are instructing the compiler to use a proxy class as a default replacement type for the interface.  Since Java is highly focused on encapsulation, and the _appearance_ of code can be customized independently of its functionality (and this is quite common), I feel it is important to be clear in "weird" cases like this that this is not a hack, and does not violate the rules of the language in any way.

Answer (score 3):

when you call

```
var x = new IDynamicCode<string>[10];
```

Constructors are not called. They are only declared.